# Increment variable as .offsetTop() increments

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am writing a custom parallaxing thing for a website I am working on.

It's very simple:

```
$('.bl-content').scroll(function(){
    $('.prlx-image img').each(function(){
        if($(this).parents('div.prlx-image').offset().top < $('.page-type--sfs .bl-content').height()){
            $(this).css('bottom', $('.page-type--sfs .bl-content').scrollTop() * -.3);
        }
    });
});
```

It basically checks to see if the image is on the page and only then starts pulling the image up slightly faster slower than the page scrolls. The problem here is that the value the image is being pulled by is the same for each image. So it works fine for any images already on the page when it loads but anything further down has already "parallaxed" out of its container by the time it gets into view.

The images are just absolutely positioned within a container div.

I need to start scrollTop from zero when the image gets scrolled into view...

UPDATE:

I have been playing around with this and think I am on to something:

```
var offset = []

$('.prlx-image').each(function(i){
    offset[i] = $(this).offset().top;
});

$('.bl-content').scroll(function(){
    $('.prlx-image img').each(function(i){
        if($(this).parents('div.prlx-image').offset().top < $('.page-type--sfs .bl-content').outerHeight()){
            $(this).css('bottom', ($('.page-type--sfs .bl-content').scrollTop() * -.3) - offset[i]);
        }
    });
});
```

So now if I subtract the value of i from the value of scrollTop() theoretically that should work....but for some reason it is not working :(

If it helps the html each image is contained in looks like this:

```
<div class="prlx-image">
    <img src="/assets/uploads/menncars.jpg" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
prlx-image{
    height: 350px;
    margin: 30px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.prlx-image img{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: How about checking "$(this).parents('div.prlx-image').offset().bottom" is in view and scroll only then?

Comment: Unfortunately that is not my problem....its the scrollTop() value. This is always the same for all 3 images I have on the page and is also what I am currently using as a value to adjust my image position. The thing is I need the scrollTop var as that value changes accordingly when you scroll but I need to adjust it for each image I have, considering each images starting position on the page...if that makes sense...